# Sequelize many-to-many association: getter/setter methods do not exist

Tags: node.js, postgresql, many-to-many, sequelize.js

### What are you doing?

I'm trying to create a many-to-many relationship between two tables: 'routes' and 'tags'. However, when I try to use the getter methods that sequelize is meant to create, I get an error saying it's not a method.

My model definitions are as follows:

**models/route:**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var route = sequelize.define('route', {
    name: {
//some attributes
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        route.belongsToMany(models.tag, { through: models.route_tag, as: 'tag' })
      }
    }
  });
  return route;
};
```

**models/tag:**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var tag = sequelize.define('tag', {
//some attributes
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        tag.belongsToMany(models.route, { through: models.route_tag, as: 'route' })
      }
    }
  });
  return tag;
};
```

**models/route_tag:**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var route_tag = sequelize.define('route_tag', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    route_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    tag_id:DataTypes.INTEGER
  })
  return route_tag;
};
```

And I'm trying to access the getter method in the following seed file:

```
const route = require('../models').route
const tag = require('../models').tag


module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return route.findOne({where:{name:'routeName'}}).then(myRoute=>{
      return route.findOne({where:{name:'crackName'}}).then(myTag=>{
        return myRoute.addTag(myTag)
      })
    })
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.bulkDelete('route_tags')
  }
};
```

### What do you expect to happen?

From what I've read in the docs and from various tutorials/forums, my impression is that the belongsToMany association being set in the route and tag models will automatically add the addTag method to an instance of a route, and the addRoute method to an instance of a tag.

### What is actually happening?

When I try to run the seed file, I get an error saying:

> *ERROR: myRoute.addTag is not a function*

I feel like I must be making an error somewhere in the way I'm declaring the association, but I've been comparing my code to the documentation as well as other examples I've found online (most notably this one: https://codeburst.io/sequelize-migrations-setting-up-associations-985d29b61ee7) and I can't find where the error is. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access sequelize model methods in the seeding files and associations are not initalized by that time.

You can use queryInterface.bulkInsert() if you are getting the data from findOne query by specifying the foreign keys